# can't set JAVA_HOME because can't find where Java JDK 1.7 installed

Tags: java, macos, installation

I've just downloaded latest Java JDK for Mac OSX (jdk-7u17-macosx-x64.dmg) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

I have it installed, but I can't find where it has been installed so that I could setup JAVA_HOME.

```
notebook:work askar$ ls -al /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1 Jul 29  2012 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current -> A
```

Today is March 11, 2013. Here it shows Jul 29, 2012...

Answer (score 16):

Use the `/usr/libexec/java_home` utility which returns the path to the preferred JVM version.
With `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` you can retrieve a list of all installed JVMs.

The easiest way to set up `$JAVA_HOME` is:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

This will always set the path to the latest JVM, so you don't have to update it after upgrading java.

Comment: Thanks. This gave me three versions. Now, will figure out setting up $JAVA_HOME

Comment: I have /usr/libexec/java_home on my mac (installed jdk with *.dmg) but not on my linux box through direct download and decompress.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo `/usr/libexec/java_home`
```

You can use this command to find the java home in mac os.

Comment: \`command\` is not a problem, $(command) is preferred